# How to generate uniformly distributed random reals for custom types without reinventing the wheel?

Tags: c++, random, floating-point

I was going to use `std::uniform_real_distribution` with some non-builtin floating-point-like types, e.g. [`half_float::half`](http://half.sourceforge.net/half_8hpp_source.html) or [`boost::multiprecision::float128`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html). But what I get is

> /opt/gcc-5.2/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/random.h:1868:7: error: static assertion failed: template argument not a floating point type

from g++ 5.2. Here's the example program (compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -fext-numeric-literals test.cpp -o test`):

```
#include <random>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
#include <half.hpp>

template<typename Float>
void test()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<Float> rnd(Float(1),Float(10));
}

int main()
{
    test<float>();
    test<double>();
    test<long double>();
    test<boost::multiprecision::float128>(); // doesn't compile
    test<half_float::half>(); // doesn't compile
}
```

So, how is one supposed to generate uniformly distributed random reals for such custom types? Is there a way to go without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: How about defining a function that takes 1 to n floats and returns your favourite float type? Then have random float(s) as input(s), perhaps as default arguments.

Comment: @lorro do you mean just a function converting float types from builtin type to the type I need? But that will not leave the distribution uniform.

Comment: I mean 'function' in mathematical sense: an 1-to-1 mapping between elements of your custom float and N standard floats (or vice versa, if your float is smaller than the std. float). It's easier to explain with ints: pseudocode: `int64_t getint64(int32_t a, int32_t b) { return int64_t(a) << 32 + b; }`. Such a function can be created for all types (perhaps by ignoring some bits from the most significant ones).

Comment: @lorro the tricky part in defining such a function for floats would be to make sure that for N arguments distributed uniformly on `[a,b) intersected with the set of values of input type` it would give out the result which is distributed uniformly on `[a,b) intersected with the set of values of output types`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard random number facilities which work with `RealType` type as defined in the Standard, must have `float`, `double` or `long double` as type template argument, as in 26.5.1.1.d:

> Throughout this subclause 26.5, the effect of instantiating a template:
>
> <...>
>
> d) that has a template type parameter named `RealType` is undefined unless the corresponding template argument is cv-unqualified and is one of `float`, `double`, or `long double`.

One solution is to replace `std::uniform_real_distribution` with `boost::random::uniform_real_distribution`. The latter does accept non-builtin float types. Here's an example with a reasonable type<sup>*</sup>:

```
#include <random>
#include <boost/random/uniform_real_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

template<typename Float>
void test()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    boost::random::uniform_real_distribution<Float> rnd(Float(1),Float(10));
}

int main()
{
    test<float>();
    test<double>();
    test<long double>();
    test<boost::multiprecision::float128>();
}
```

<sub><sup>*</sup>`half_float::half` doesn't work because its multiplication by a constant results in a `float`, while `half_float::half(float)` constructor is explicit, and Boost's implementation doesn't call it explicitly</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution), `uniform_real_distribution` is defined as:

```
template< class RealType = double >
class uniform_real_distribution;
```

Where `RealType` is:

> The result type generated by the generator. The effect is undefined if this is not one of float, double, or long double.

It seems that your compiler explicitly forbids to use a custom type as a solution to deal with (let me say) *unaccepted types*. Therefore I would say that you have no chance to get it working.

Comment: OK, but the actual question is what are some good alternatives if any, i.e. something I could use instead of making up my own implementation of uniform distribution.

Comment: @Ruslan You can use `float`, `double` or `long double` as a type. That's all. Or are you looking for an alternative to `uniform_real_distribution`?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an alternative mechanism which would work for other float types.

Comment: @Ruslan They are different types than built-in ones. The best you can do with the standard template library is write a generator that uses internally `uniform_real_distribution` and `float`s and returns the type you want. Anyway, the conversion will deflate probably the benefits of using a `uniform_real_distribution`.